# Getting the current time and then displaying it with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, time

```js
function timeNow(i) {
        var d = new Date(),
            h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours(),
            m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes();
        i.value = h + ':' + m;
    }
    document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard-hello"></div>
```

I am attempting to get the current time with my `timeNow` function and then I am wanting it to show up in my `#dashboard-hello` id. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it doesn't show up. If I take out the () in `timeNow` when I try to do innerHTML, the whole function prints

```
function timeNow(i) { var d = new Date(), h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours(), m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes(); i.value = h + ':' + m; }
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[click for jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4t3w6q0/)

ps - When I get the time working, how could I structure this into an if statement for when it is 4:00-11:30 to say "Good Morning", then the same for afternoon/evening?

Updated code:

```
function timeNow() {

        var d = new Date(),
        h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours() : '') + d.getHours(),
        m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : '') + d.getMinutes();

        // To check for a time range (between 4:: and 11:30 here):
        var morningTime = (h >= 4 && h <= 11) && m <= 30 ? true : false;
        var noonTime    = (h >= 12 && h <= 17) && m <= 30 ? true : false;
        var nightTime   = (h >= 18 && h <= 3) && m <= 30 ? true : false;
        console.log(morningTime);

        if (morningTime == true) {
            return "Good Morning";
        }
        else if (noonTime == true) {
            return "Good Afterboon";
        }
        else if (nightTime == true) {
            return "Good Evening";
        }
       /*  h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours();
        m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes();*/

        //return h + ':' + m;
    }
    document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow() + ', name';
```

Comment: You're not passing any arguments into `timeNow` when you invoke it.

Comment: Your function is not returning anything. Its should end with something like `return h + ':' + m;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to set the `innerHTML` of your `div` to the result of the  function, so the function must return a value, rather than attempt to set the `value` property on the `div` (`div`s don't have a value property).

```js
function timeNow() {
  
  var d = new Date(),
  // When the hour or minute is less than 10, you want to return 0 plus the hour or minute.
  // You were just returning 0.
  h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours(),
  m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes();

  // If you are going to set something to a function, the function must return a value
  return h + ':' + m;
}
    '
document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard-hello"></div>
```

To check the time to see if it is between 4:00 and 11:30, you'd need some additional tests:

```js
function timeNow() {
  
  var d = new Date();
  
  var h = d.getHours();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  
  // To check for a time range (between 4:: and 11:30 here):
  var specialTime = (h >= 4 && h <= 11) && m <= 30 ? true : false;
  
  
  // To check for a time range (between 4:: and 11:30 here):
  var morningTime = (h >= 4 && h <= 11) && m <= 30 ? true : false;
  var noonTime    = (h >= 12 && h <= 17) && m <= 30 ? true : false;
  var nightTime   = (h >= 18 && h <= 3) && m <= 30 ? true : false;
 
  var greeting = "";
  
  if (morningTime) {
    greeting = "Good Morning";
  } else if (noonTime) {
    greeting = "Good Afternoon";
  } else if (nightTime) {
    greeting = "Good Evening";
  }
  
  h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours();
  m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes();
  
  
  // If you are going to set something to a function, the function must return a value
  return h + ':' + m + " (" + greeting + ")";
}
document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard-hello"></div>
```

Comment: Also, `timeNow()` doesn't need any arguments this way. You could remove the `i` completely.

Comment: Yep. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks! So if I wanted to check if the `h + ':' + m` is between 4:00 and 11:30 how would that if statement be structured?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for the extra help. After setting up the variable, when I put it in the if statement, would I just check `specialTime` on h and m?

Comment: @ScottMarcus or this: `if (specialTime == true) {
            return "Good Morning";
        }`

Comment: Yes. That's it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I just updated my question with my new code. Do you see why it would be showing as undefined?

Comment: @Paul I've updated my answer again to show what you are trying to do. Also, note that you don't actually need to compare values against `true` in an `if` statement since `if ` conditions are implicitly tested for `true`. Additionally, you don't always want to use `return` when a value is calculated because that will exit the function. You can store a value in a variable and then return a combination of values.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code. You need to return a value from function if you are assigning value to HTML element.

```js
function timeNow() {
        var d = new Date(),
            h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours(),
            m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes();
        return h + ':' + m;
    }
    document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard-hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code (sorta) including the morning/afternoon/evening qualifier

```
function timeNow(i) {           
    var d = new Date();        
    var afternoon=new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(),11,30);        
    var evening =new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(),17,30);
    var greeting=(d.getTime()>evening.getTime()?"Evening":(d.getTime()>afternoon.getTime()?"Afternoon":"Morning"));

    return greeting + " " + ("00"+d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00"+d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

}
document.getElementById('dashboard-hello').innerHTML = timeNow();
```